# Какую функцию выполняет .filter(fieldNames::remove)?

Tags: java

Есть следующая часть кода на Java

```
List<String> fieldNames = new ArrayList<>(allFields.size() + 10);

List<String> result = PRE_SORTED_FIELDS_LIST
                .stream()
                .filter(fieldNames::remove)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Правильно ли я понимаю, что строка `.filter(fieldNames::remove)` выполнят фильтрацию значений в `List<String> fieldNames` и возращает в `.collect(Collectors.toList());` только те значения, которые дали результат `true` а те значения которые дали `false` были удалены методом `remove`?

Вопрос возможно банальный, но до этого с Java ни разу не работал.

Comment: Не удалены, а не включены в результат фильтрации

Comment: А в целом все правильно понял?
и еще тогда подвпросик, `true` - это получается есть значение отличающиеся от `null`?

Comment: Метод `remove` возвращает примитивный тип `boolean`, этот тип строго либо `true`, либо `false`.

Comment: Только не путайте его с другим методом `remove`, который принимает индекс элемента в коллекции, а не объект.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод `filter` преобразует стрим в новый стрим, в котором будут только те элементы, которые удовлетворяют условию. Стримы в Java ленивые: пока не вызовется `collect`, ничего не начнет считаться.

Метод `remove` ищет переданный объект в коллекции и удаляет его, возвращая `true`, если объект удалось найти. И `false` — если такого объекта нет.

Конструкция `fieldNames::remove` в Java — это метод-референс. Чтобы было понятнее, его можно развернуть в обычную лямбду:

```java
.filter(item -> fieldNames.remove(item))
```

Чтобы совсем все было понятно, весь ваш код можно преобразовать в обычный си-стайл:

```java
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (String item : PRE_SORTED_FIELDS_LIST) {
    if (fieldNames.remove(item)) {
        result.add(item);
    }
}
```

Все эти преобразования автоматически за вас может сделать Intellij IDEA, если вы работаете в ней. Для этого нажать <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> и выбрать соответствующее преобразование.

Comment: Вы наверно хотели сказать `remove` вместо `rename`

Comment: Да, спасибо, поправил